# kinetic js code assist for Aptana Studio

Tags: eclipse-plugin, aptana, kineticjs, code-assist

I have just started discovering [Kinetic JS](http://kineticjs.com/). I would want to know if there's any code assist plugin for Aptana Studio(personally my fav) or jsb file. Any other specific editors, suggestions please?

Thanks,
Nuthan

Comment: Not at the moment. The best you can hope for is that when you include KineticJS as a source, that Aptana will recognize and grab the methods.